# Write Python version independent code: struct.pack

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Let's assume you have the following Python2 Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import struct

struct.pack('s', 'hello')
```

This works fine under Python2, but it won't run under Python3, as the implementation of struct.pack changed. struct.pack now expects a bytes object for a string identifier and not a string any more. The fix for running this code under Python3 would be something like:
`struct.pack('s', bytes('hello', 'utf-8'))`. But again, this code will not run under Python2 :-)

I'm trying to code version independent as I don't want to force anybody to install python2 or 3.

What would be the best approach for getting this piece of code version independent?

Comment: Python 2 `str` *is* a bytestring. It is not `struct` that changed, it is the Python string object. Python 2 `unicode` became `str` in Python 3, Python 2 `str` became `bytes` in Python 3.

Comment: So your problem is a generic *how do I produce a bytestring in both Python 2 and 3* issue. `b'hello'` will work in both Python 2 and 3 if you are using literals.

Comment: Well in fact I use a variable rather than a literal. But wait, look at the documentation of struct. It states that the python types changed from string to bytes.

Comment: Yes, because the type was renamed, basically.

Comment: You are basically producing bytestrings in Python 2, Unicode strings in Python 3. It could be the correct fix is to use Unicode everywhere (and thus always encode when using `struct.pack()`, regardless of the Python version).

Comment: I just checked the types, in Python2 it used to be "<type 'str'>", in Python3 it's "<class 'str'>"

Comment: Yes, and the Python 3 `str` type is the same thing as `unicode` in Python 2. You'd encode `unicode` values in Python 2 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python 2 `str` type was basically renamed to `bytes` in Python 3, while the `unicode` type became `str`. You are in essence sending bytestrings in Python 2 and Unicode strings in Python 3 to `struct.pack()`.

It could be the correct fix is to use Unicode everywhere in both Python 2 and 3 (and thus always encode when using `struct.pack()`, regardless of the Python version).

The alternative is to use an isinstance test:

```
value = 'hello'
if not isinstance(value, bytes):
    vaule = value.encode('utf8')
```

This works in both Python 2 and 3, because in Python 2 `bytes` is an alias for `str`.